# Get Contact ID from Mobile SDK on Android/iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, mobile, sdk

I'm trying to pass the Contact ID to a dimension for tracking Analytics. How would I go about getting the Contact ID value from Salesforce?

I'm using the MarketingCloudSDK pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the Contact ID without making an API call into Contacts.